# Sending System.out to a file and Commons Logging

Tags: java, shell, logging, apache-commons-logging

I am using commons logging:

```
  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

Why those logs doesn't go into the log file when I run

```
sh Main 2>&1 > logfile
```

I am using the default properties and no log4j.properties are in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the redirections backwards. They're processed from left to right. Try this:

```
sh Main > logfile 2>&1
```

Comment: I checked a few scripts my admins deployed and indeed I am backwards.  Thanks for the help.